# ¿Por qué siempre tengo problemas con flexbox?

Tags: css

Siempre `flexbox` me trae problemas.
Por ejemplo, le doy al contenedor display `flex` y al hijo le doy `flex-direction: flex end;` y no funciona, se queda en el lugar.

Tambien me pasa con el grid.
Le doy display grid y le doy `grid-template-columns: repeat (3, 1fr);` por ejemplo, pero por alguna razón el codigo decide ignorar esto y seguir en row.

Comment: Sin un [mcve] imposible ayudarte

Comment: Como dice BetaM debes poner un ejemplo mínimo y verificable. De todas formas, flex-direction: flex end no existe en CSS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

Comment: Es al contenedor que le debes establecer la propiedad `flex-direction` y no al _hijo_. Además, el valor `flex end` ni `flex-end` es válido en la propiedad `flex-direction`. Los valores válidos en `flex-direction` son `row` y `column`.

Comment: `flex-direction` se utiliza para cambiar el eje de los elementos _flexibles_ (_hijos_). Si su valor es `column` los elementos se van a _apilar_ verticamente, de lo contrario, horizontalmente, que es su valor por defecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `flex-direction` debe ir en el container padre junto a `display: flex`. `flex-end` aplica a las propiedades `flex-direction` y `justify-content`. Por lo tanto la estructura del componente padre debería ser por ejemplo:

```
.container: {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Sin ver el código qué ocasiona el problema es difícil ayudar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pense que el `justify-content: flex-end;` se le debía poner al hijo.
Ahi estaba mi error.